# How to access "isUserInRole" in jsp using JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl, roles

I am making a JSP/Servlet CRUD with MySQL. I currently have 2 roles in my project: manager and employee. I want to display different data based on these roles. How do I access the `request.isUserInRole()` method without using scriptlets? I heard that using scriptlets are bad.

I temporarily have the following code:

`<c:if <%request.isUserInRole("manager");%>=true>
<!-- Display something -->
<c:if <%request.isUserInRole("employee");%>=true>
<!-- Display something -->`

But I get an error:

`HTTP Status 500 - /protected/listUser.jsp (line: 97, column: 9) Unterminated &lt;c:if tag`

Which is probably some problem with JSTL mixing in with a scriptlet.

How would I access the `isUserInRole()` method in my JSP page with only JSTL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify condition with test attribute (which [is required](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/if.html)).

It could be achieved with

```
  <% request.setAttribute("isManager", request.isUserInRole("manager")); %>
  <c:if test="${requestScope.isManager}">
    <!-- Display manager -->
  </c:if>
  <c:if test="${!requestScope.isManager}">
    <!-- Display employee -->
  </c:if>
```

or with

```
  <% request.setAttribute("isManager", request.isUserInRole("manager")); %>
  <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${requestScope.isManager}">
      <!-- Display manager -->
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
      <!-- Display employee -->
    </c:otherwise>
  </c:choose>
```

Comment: This only works once. I put a button under the `<c:if test="${isManager}">`. When I go to test it on the GUI, the button disappears after I click it. If I reload the page it comes back, but that isn't too user-friendly. Any help?

Comment: That is another issue, you should create a new post about it. What is that button for (add code with it to the question if it's appropriate)? Use `requestScope`: `<% request.setAttribute("isManager", request.isUserInRole("manager")); %>`